# Noetherian stalks imply locally Noetherian

Tags: schemes

Is there an example of a non-Noetherian integral affine scheme with Noetherian space and Noetherian stalks? What if we replace "integral" with "reduced"?

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/q/317222/82179

Answer (score 3):

Example 2.3 in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-158-02/S0002-9947-1971-0280472-2/S0002-9947-1971-0280472-2.pdf)  of  Bill Heinzer and Jack Ohm is the coordinate ring of a non-Noetherian affine integral scheme with Noetherian space and Noetherian stalks.